# CURL (PHP) returns server IP instead of the NGINX listen IP

Tags: php, nginx, curl, server, ip

I am trying to use CURL (PHP) to access a web page that only allows 300 requests per hour. This is an API. I have created 3 hosts on each with a different IPv6 address so I can bypass the limit, but when I test my IP, the same IP comes out for all 3 hosts. My question is: How can I use my IPv6 addresses to bypass the limit of the API? Is it even the correct method?

I have created 3 hosts in NGINX each with a different IPv6 and 3 subdomains

`proxy1.example.com > assigned: 2a07:5741:0:xxx::1 > curl returns: 94.xxx.189.112`

`proxy2.example.com > assigned: 2a07:5741:0:xxx::2 > curl returns: 94.xxx.189.112`

`proxy2.example.com > assigned: 2a07:5741:0:xxx::3 > curl returns: 94.xxx.189.112`

This is my NGINX configuration:

```
server {
    listen [2a07:5741:0:xxx::1]:80 ipv6only=on;
    root /var/www/proxy;

    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  proxy1.example.org;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;       
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

And this is my PHP code I test  my IP address:

```
$url = "https://www.whatsmyip.org/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

Any idea?

Comment: If all the hosts are on the same private network, behind the same NAT router, or proxy server, or whatever, then they will all have the same _public_ IP address, regardless of what IP you assign to them for the local network. And the public IP is the only one that the remote API can see

Comment: More info: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation

Comment: Equally even if they're 3 subdomains hosted on a single public server, the likelihood is that for _outbound_ requests they all go through the same gateway (and thus share its public IP). The IPs/subdomains you've configured in nginx will only be applicable to inbound requests

Comment: Does it mean there is no way to use my IPv6 addresses to make a proxy?

Comment: I got a little VPS with /64 blocks IPv6 addresses and I assigned 3 of them to my networking file.

Comment: Like I said, you've configured them for inbound access, but not outbound. You'd need a separate internet gateway for each application on the VPS if you wanted them to have separate public IP addresses for outbound communication

Comment: Thanks 4 info, I bought 10 Proxies for $1,5 and it works now